# Why isn't this a [PARTIAL] solution to Lewy's Example

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, partial-differential-equations

I was considering the example of the equation from: https://people.maths.ox.ac.uk/trefethen/pdectb/lewy2.pdf

$$ \frac{\partial f}{\partial x} + i \frac{\partial f}{\partial y} - 2i(x + iy) \frac{\partial f}{\partial t} = \begin{cases} e^{-\frac{1}{t}} & t \ge 0 \\ 0  & t< 0\end{cases}$$

Which is determined to be unsolvable. Something interesting to  consider though is the following:

$$\frac{\partial f}{\partial x} + i \frac{\partial f}{\partial y} - 2i(x + iy) \frac{\partial f}{\partial t} = \left( \frac{\partial f}{\partial x}  - 2ix \frac{\partial f}{\partial t} \right) + i\left( \frac{\partial f}{\partial y}  - 2iy \frac{\partial f}{\partial t} \right) $$

$$e^{-\frac{1}{t}} = 1 - \frac{1}{t} + \frac{1}{2t^2} - \frac{1}{3!t^3} ... $$

$$\left( \frac{\partial f}{\partial x}  - 2ix \frac{\partial f}{\partial t} \right) = \frac{\omega}{t^n} \rightarrow $$

$$ f =  W(y) + \frac{\omega x}{n!t^n} \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{k!(n+k)!(4ix)^kx^k }{(2k+1)!t^k} $$

(Amongst other solutions too), observe that if $|x| < \frac{1}{4}$ and $|t| >> 1$ then this is well defined.

Then wouldn't

$$ f(t)= \begin{cases}  \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \left[ \frac{(-1)^n}{(n!)^2t^n} \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \left[ \frac{k!(n+k)!(4ix)^kx^{k+1} }{2(2k+1)!t^k} +  \frac{k!(n+k)!(4iy)^ky^{k+1}}{2i(2k+1)!t^k} \right] \right] & t \ge 0 \\ C & t<0 \end{cases}$$

Be a solution to the Lewy equation, over some $t,x,y$ in the domain (for small $t$, and large $x,y$ of course it remains undefined).

I find this odd, unless it means I should understand Lewy's equation as not having any globally well defined solution, the fact this exists, symbolically , and does converge to something meaningful for certain $t,x,y$ violates the condition that Lewy's example has no solution, ANYWHERE.

Comment: Sorry I had a typo, the series is correct, it was always meant to be for $e^{-\frac{1}{t}}$

Comment: Is your $f(t)$ continuous at $t=0$?

Comment: @ArcticChar I don't think so, after all it involves negative powers of $t$

Comment: Note that your example only shows that there is no solution at around $t=0$ (since it is not analytic there). But your equation might have solution around where $t\neq 0$. To make a counterexample you need to construct  a function which is nowhere analytic.